# R: tracing factory-generated functions in packages

Tags: r

Create and load a toy R package, with only two functions:

```r
functionFactory <- function() {
  return(function(...) print(...))
}

generatedF <- functionFactory()
```

There are two seemingly equivalent ways of getting the function: `generatedF` and `get("generatedF", asNamespace("toyPackage"))`, but it seems if I want to `trace` the function I have to do it separately for both modes:

```r
trace(generatedF, tracer=function() print("1"))
generatedF(3)   # traced
get("generatedF", asNamespace("toyPackage")) (3) # not traced  !

trace(generatedF, tracer=function() print("1"), where=asNamespace("toyPackage"))
generatedF(3)   # traced
get("generatedF", asNamespace("toyPackage")) (3) # also traced
```

Even worse, it seems the first `trace` call "*splits*" the function. Restart R, reload toyPackage and try -

```r
trace(generatedF, tracer=function() print("1"))

class(generatedF)         # functionWithTrace
class(get("generatedF", asNamespace("toyPackage")))   # "function"
```

Am I missing something elementary? Could this be an R issue?   I tried to poke around `methods::.TraceWithMethods` but with no success.

Comment: Is this really unique to generated functions? What if you just attached toyPackage and traced a standard function?

Comment: @dash I'm afraid it is unique to generated functions